# Curl Working but Python Requests/Sessions gives 404 error

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, influxdb

I am trying access the InfluxDB remotely from a `Linux` box. When i use the CURL command, i'm able to get the database details -

```
curl http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:8086/query --data-urlencode "q=SHOW DATABASES"
{"results":[{"statement_id":0,"series":[{"name":"databases","columns":["name"],"values":[["_internal"],["ExampleDatabase"]]}]}]}
```

When the same is tried using `Requests` Python, I get **404 page not found**

```
import requests
shorturl = 'http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:8086/query --data-urlencode "q=SHOW DATABASES"'
r = requests.get(shorturl)
print (r.text)
```

Is there anything that has to be passed to make it work from Python. When i try to hit the URL - *http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:8086/query --data-urlencode "q=SHOW DATABASES"* in the browser, i get the 404 message. Telnet from Linux box to the box where InfluxDB is hosted is working.

Python v2.7.5. I tried all the possible ways given over the internet but none of them worked.

Kindly clarify

Comment: I am not expert in python requests, but shorturl you got looks like a wrong url to me. you probably need to do something like r = requests.get(url_link, params=payload)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i was saying on the comments, your short url with --data-urlencode which is correct for curl is not valid for python requests, please try this,

```
payload = {'q': 'SHOW DATABASES'}
shorturl = 'http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:8086/query'
r = requests.get(shorturl, params=payload)
print (r.text)
```

you can learn more on request here http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/

Comment: happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

--data-urlencode is a curl option to pass POST parameters to your HTTP request.

You should use the appropriated method with request to get the same behavior. --data-urlencode is not valid in python

This may work :

```
import requests
shorturl = 'http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:8086/query'
r = requests.post(shorturl, data={'q': 'SHOW DATABASES'})
```

See https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: thanks man for the info on the --data-urlencode part. worked like a charm!